# Adding to dictionary dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I 'm having an array of dictionary like so...

```
[
  {
    "id" : "3",
    "sellingPrice" : "520",
    "quantity" : "15"
  },
  {
    "id" : "5",
    "sellingPrice" : "499",
    "quantity" : "-1"
  },
  {
    "id" : "8",
    "sellingPrice" : "500",
    "quantity" : "79"
  }
]
```

Now I want to add to the dictionary another key called `remaining_balance` with a value of 420,499 & 500 respectively. How can I achieve this..? Hope somebody can help...

Comment: Are you asking in Swift? Please elaborate the question..

Comment: loop through array, get hold of dictionary inside, append the dictionary with remaining_balance after converting nsdictionary to nsmutabledictionary and save that dictionary to array at the same index

Comment: I think you would be much better off if instead of an array of dictionaries you would have an array of classes or structs. 

If you want a possible solution to that appraoch I can post an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to add a value to your dictionary that is an array:

```
var arrDict = Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>()  //Your array
arrDict.append(["id":"3","sellingPrice":"520","quantity":"13"])
arrDict.append(["id":"5","sellingPrice":"43","quantity":"32"])
arrDict.append(["id":"8","sellingPrice":"43","quantity":"33"])


let arrValue = ["420","499","500"] //Your remaining value in array


print("Before ",arrDict)
for (index,dict) in arrDict.enumerated() {
    var dictCopy = dict //assign to var variable
    dictCopy["remaining_balance"] = arrValue[index]
    arrDict[index] = dictCopy //Replace at index with new dictionary
}
print("After ",arrDict)
```

**EDIT**

If you are able keep an index of an array it would be possible, 
Assuming that you have the index of an array

```
var dictCopy = arrDict[index]
dictCopy["remaining_balance"] = "666" //Your calculated value
arrDict[index] = dictCopy //Replace at index with new dictionary
```

Comment: Actually @Salman Ghumsani the values of 420,499 & 500 are not hardcoded. These are obtained from a calculation. A certain parameter called `partial amt` (say for eg. 20) is first compared to the 1st S.P of 520 & since its less than 520 the value is subtracted and the rem.bal in this case would be 500. Now since the amt. 20 is used up, the other 2 will have `remaining_bal` as they are(since there is nothing to subtract from). So can I use your approach in such a scenario....?

Comment: You Could achieve it by mapping the array :) check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47181533/5501940) one.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have an array of dictionaries like so:

```
var arrayOfDictionaries = [
    [
      "id": 3,
      "sellingPrice": 520,
      "quantity": 15
    ]
]
```

It is important that `arrayOfDictionaries` is not a `let` constant, otherwise it is considered **immutable** and you can not call `append` on it.

Now you init a new dictionary like:

```
let newDictionary = [
    "id": 10,
    "remaining_balance": 420,
    "quantity": 15
]
```

Now add the `newDictionary` like

```
arrayOfDictionaries.append(newDictionary)
```

### If the order is important

If the order is important there are a couple of ways to go about that.

When calling `append` the new value (in this case the new dictionary) will always be inserted at the bottom of the array.

If for some reason you can not call `append` in the correct order you could use `insert`, which inserts your dictionary at a specific position.

Yet another way is to append the values wildly and after you are done, call `sort` on the array.

### Improvement Tips

Notice that for the values I did not use strings, as you only have numbers like `"id" : 30`.

Also, if you want the second key to be called `remaining_balance` you should call the first key `selling_price` instead of `sellingPrice`. Because of conistency.

### Alternative approach

As far as I have understood you are trying to implement some software that is responsibly for selling some products.

I think you are tackling this problem from a completely wrong side. 
I think you should read about database relationships. Selling products actually is a very common problem.

Maybe [this](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/modeling-a-database-for-recording-sales-part-2-creating-tables-for-products-and-services) will help you. I would offer a possible solution myself, but I think this misses the point of your question.

If you decide to use the database approach, you won't necessarily have to use a database. You can take the approach and implement it using simple structs/classes/arrays.

Comment: .@Shanakor there's a doubt. How can I specify which value will go into which dictionary. i.e. I do I specify 420 will go at first, 499 at second & the other element at 3rd...?

Comment: Also I apologise, because I have made some syntax errors. I have fixed them now. (First time answering a question on StackOverflow for me)

Comment: No worries, @Shanakor...:)

Comment: So, how did it go?  Make sure to accept an answer if your question has been resolved.

Comment: Actually the issue got resolved from a different approach...But thanks for the inputs. Have given an upvote...:)

Answer (score 0):

```
var newKV = [["remaining_balance": "420"],["remaining_balance": "490"],["remaining_balance": "500"]]
let array = [["id":"3", "sellingPrice":"520", "quantity":"15"], ["id":"5", "sellingPrice":"520", "quantity":"15"], ["id":"8", "sellingPrice":"520", "quantity":"15"]]

let newArray = array.enumerated().map { (index : Int, value: [String: String]) -> [String: String] in
    var dic = value
    dic.merge(newKV[index]) { (_, new) -> String in
        new
    }
    return dic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it by *mapping* your array:

```
var myArray = [["id": "3", "sellingPrice": "520", "quantity" : "15"], ["id": "5", "sellingPrice": "499", "quantity" : "-1"], ["id": "8", "sellingPrice": "500", "quantity" : "79"]]

print(myArray)
/*
 [["id": "3", "sellingPrice": "520", "quantity": "15"],
 ["id": "5", "sellingPrice": "499", "quantity": "-1"],
 ["id": "8", "sellingPrice": "500", "quantity": "79"]]
 */
print("___________________")

var remainingBalanceDesriedValue = 420
myArray = myArray.map { (dict: [String: String]) -> [String: String] in
    var copyDict = dict
    copyDict["remaining_balance"] = "\(remainingBalanceDesriedValue)"

    remainingBalanceDesriedValue = (remainingBalanceDesriedValue == 420) ? 499 : (remainingBalanceDesriedValue == 499) ? 500 : 420

    return copyDict
}

print(myArray)
/*
 [["sellingPrice": "520", "quantity": "15", "id": "3", "remaining_balance": "420"],
 ["sellingPrice": "499", "quantity": "-1", "id": "5", "remaining_balance": "499"],
 ["sellingPrice": "500", "quantity": "79", "id": "8", "remaining_balance": "500"]]
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this question lacks an `extension` answer, yes.. I'm gonna be that guy, so here it is. This could be made more generic by supporting other types of dictionaries, feel free to pitch in ;)

Inspiration from @eason's answer.

```
var newKV = [["remaining_balance": "420"],["remaining_balance": "490"],["remaining_balance": "500"]]
var array = [["id":"3", "sellingPrice":"520", "quantity":"15"], ["id":"5", "sellingPrice":"520", "quantity":"15"], ["id":"8", "sellingPrice":"520", "quantity":"15"]]

extension Array where Element == [String: String] {

    enum UniquingKeysStrategy {
        case old
        case new
    }

    mutating func merge(with target: Array<Element>, uniquingKeysWith: UniquingKeysStrategy = .new) {

        self = self.merged(with: target)
    }

    func merged(with target: Array<Element>, uniquingKeysWith strategy: UniquingKeysStrategy = .new) -> Array<Element> {

        let base = self.count > target.count ? self : target
        let data = self.count > target.count ? target : self

        return data.enumerated().reduce(into: base, {
            result, data in

            result[data.offset]
                .merge(data.element, uniquingKeysWith: {
                    old, new in

                    if strategy == .new { return new }

                    return old
                })
        })
    }
}

let mergedArrays = newKV.merged(with: array, uniquingKeysWith: .old)

array.merge(with: newKV)
```

Happy Coding :)